# How to provide an initialization vector with XML Encryption Syntax

Tags: xml, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, xml-encryption

I encrypt my data with AES with a key and a random IV. This key I encrypt with RSA and include it in my `EncryptedData` as seen below. I need to include the IV too but how do I include it with XML Encryption Syntax as the `KeyInfo` element is already occupied by the `EncryptedKey` element?

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbf" />
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                <KeySize>256</KeySize>
                <OAEPparams>AA==</OAEPparams>
                <DigestMethod xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            </EncryptionMethod>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <KeyName>client provided public key</KeyName>
            </KeyInfo>
            <CipherData>
                <CipherValue>...</CipherValue>
            </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
    </KeyInfo>
    <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>...</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [XMLEnc](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/#sec-Alg-Block) (see 5.2.2) the IV is placed in front of the encrypted data and is not included as a part of the key. Neither XMLEnc specification says anything about including the IV with the key during KeyTransport or KeyWrap procedure.

Comment: Yes that paragraph got me confused quite a bit, especially the "the IV, if any, could be specified as being with the cipher data, as an algorithm content element, or elsewhere." part.
So I just prepend the IV to the CipherValue Element content separated by a space?

Comment: @4485670 that's for user-defined algorithms. For specification-defined algorithms the IV goes before the encrypted data, as the next paragraph says. So it's quite clear.